# Websphere 8.5.5.0 with IceFaces 3.3.0, ace:dataTable don't work fine

Tags: jsf, jboss, websphere, icefaces, ace-datatable

I'm using ICEFaces 3.3.0. I have a problem with `<ace:dataTable/>`. When getting `rowStateVar` from `RequestMap` the result is `NULL` when running my application in Websphere 8.5.5.0, but it works fine in Jboss 7.1.1.

My code looks like this:

```
<ace:dataTable id="dataTable1"  
                var="info" value="#{manageBean.dataList}"
                         rowStateVar="rowState1"
                         stateMap="#{manageBean.stateMap1}"
                         selectionMode="single" 
                         rowSelectListener="#{manageBean.rowSelectListener1}"
                         rowUnselectListener="#{manageBean.rowDelectListener1}"
                         resizable="true" styleClass="table"> . . . </ace:dataTable>
```

Java:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("rowState1")
```

...returns NULL!